# How to write an array in a file line by line from the database?

Tags: php, file, fwrite

I can't write to file my array line-by-line. Help me to write my array line-by-line.

Code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `sceneries`") or die(mysql_error());

$file = fopen("hello.txt", 'w') or die("Can't create a new file.");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))  {
    $str =  'Код-'.$row['icao'].' Имя пользователя-'.$row['name'].' Ссылка-'.$row['link']; 
    fwrite($file, $str);
}    

fclose($file);
```

Comment: Use a `for ... each` loop.

Comment: whats the problem you face

Answer (score 1):

Using `PHP_EOL` makes it safe in different OS, and gets replace by `\n\r` or `\n` depending on the operating system. The `$str` statement would become:

```
    $str =  'Код-'.$row['icao'].' Имя пользователя-'.$row['name'].' Ссылка-'.$row['link'].PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP_EOL and new line characters also:

Using EOL:

```
$str =  'Код-'.$row['icao'].' Имя пользователя-'.$row['name'].' Ссылка-'.$row['link'].PHP_EOL;
```

Using new line:

```
$str =  'Код-'.$row['icao'].' Имя пользователя-'.$row['name'].' Ссылка-'.$row['link']."\r\n";
```